# Randomly shuffle the pages of a PDF file using pyPDF or PyPDF2

Tags: python, pdf, random, pypdf

I'm not very experienced in programming. What I'm trying to do is to randomly shuffle the pages of a pdf and output it to another pdf.

Searching online I found the following two solutions ([source 1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209637/how-can-i-shuffle-pages-from-a-pdf-file-in-a-random-order), [source 2](https://superuser.com/questions/655718/randomly-reorder-pages-in-pdf-document)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import random, sys

from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
input = PdfFileReader(sys.stdin)
output = PdfFileWriter()
pages = range(input.getNumPages())
random.shuffle(pages)
for i in pages:
     output.addPage(input.getPage(i))
output.write(sys.stdout)
```

And this one:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import random

from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader


# read input pdf and instantiate output pdf
output = PdfFileWriter()
input1 = PdfFileReader(file(sys.argv[1],"rb"))

# construct and shuffle page number list
pages = list(range(input1.getNumPages()))
random.shuffle(pages)

# display new sequence
print 'Reordering pages according to sequence:'
print pages

# add the new sequence of pages to output pdf
for page in pages:
    output.addPage(input1.getPage(page))

# write the output pdf to file
outputStream = file(sys.argv[1]+'-mixed.pdf','wb')
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()
```

I tried both (and both with PyPDF2 and pyPdf) and both indeed create a new pdf file, but this file is simply empty (and has 0KB) (when I enter, let's say "shuffle.py  new.pdf").

I'm using PyCharm and one problem I encounter (and not really understand) is that it says: "Cannot find reference 'PdfFileWriter'".

[PyCharm tells me that it cannot find the reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhZyn.jpg)

I would appreciate any help understanding what I'm doing wrong :)

**EDIT:**
As suggested by Tom Dalton, I'm posting what happens when I run the first one:

```
C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Temp\shuffle.py\venv\Scripts\python.exe "E:/Shuffle PDF/shuffle.py"
PdfReadWarning: PdfFileReader stream/file object is not in binary mode. It may not be read correctly. [pdf.py:1079]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Shuffle PDF/shuffle.py", line 5, in <module>
    input = PdfFileReader(sys.stdin)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1084, in __init__
    self.read(stream)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1689, in read
    stream.seek(-1, 2)
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Process finished with exit code 1
```

From the comments I infer that the fact that a new PDF is created is only due to me typing "shuffle.py  newfile.pdf" into the terminal :D

**EDIT 2:** I now figured it out; this now works:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
import random, sys
output = PdfFileWriter()
input = PdfFileReader(file("test.pdf", "rb"))
pages = range(input.getNumPages())
random.shuffle(pages)
for i in pages:
     output.addPage(input.getPage(i))
outputStream = file(r"output2.pdf", "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()
```

Comment: `both indeed create a new pdf file, but this file is simply empty (and has 0KB)`. It's not clear how the new file is actually created, since your program writes to stdout, so if 0 bytes are written to stdout, I don't see how you can say the new PDF is created? Is your process actually running? Have you tried adding debug statements to check that it's opening the input PDF and finding the pages etc?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! :) It creates a new file, but if the process acutally runs is a good question. It says `PdfReadWarning: PdfFileReader stream/file object is not in binary mode. It may not be read correctly. [pdf.py:1079]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Shuffle PDF/shuffle.py", line 6, in <module>
    input = PdfFileReader(sys.stdin)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1084, in __init__
    self.read(stream)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1689, in read
    stream.seek(-1, 2)
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`

Comment: Can you explain what creates the file? Your process just writes data to stdout, so I'm wondering if you are doing a stream redirection in your terminal when you run it which is why the file is created (empty). From the stacktrace you've posted it looks like your program is crashing when reading the PDF. Can you post that full stacktrace (properly formatted) as part of the question?

Comment: Thanks, again! I added the whole thing.

Comment: The error traceback suggests your process crashes at line 5 when you try to read the PDF data from stdin. I therefore can't see how it can possibly produce the empty PDF output you're talknig about. I also don't see from your command `...\python.exe "E:/Shuffle PDF/shuffle.py"` how you are passing data to the process' stdin, so even if you were reading stdin in binary mode I think it will still fail because you're not giving it data. It feels like you don't really understnad the input / output system, so it might make sense to do an online python tutorial before you try something more complex.